# How can symlink affect loading persistence.xml

Tags: linux, hibernate, jpa, persistence, symlink

In my project there're two different persistence.xml appearing in two different jar files after building. If I run application using command like this

```
/jre/v1.7.0_21/bin/java -cp patch:/path_to_app_jars/*:. org.somepath.MainClass
```

one of them is loaded but if I run it using symlink another one is peaked up

```
bin/ -> path_to_app_jars
/jre/v1.7.0_21/bin/java -cp patch:/bin/*:. org.somepath.MainClass
```

And this result is consistent regardless of what else I change.
How could that be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is that the expanded jars are returned in a different order when using the symlink, and it is loading the `persistence.xml` from the first jar listed.

As described in the [java documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/solaris/classpath.html), the order in which the jar files are returned when using a directory wildcard (*) is unpredictable. In order to always have the same jar loaded first, the solution is to list the jars explicitly in the classpath instead of using a directory wildcard:

> The order in which the JAR files in a directory are enumerated in the
>   expanded class path is not specified and may vary from platform to
>   platform and even from moment to moment on the same machine. A
>   well-constructed application should not depend upon any particular
>   order. If a specific order is required then the JAR files can be
>   enumerated explicitly in the class path.

Comment: This must be because of this but it surprises me by the level of consistency it is reproduced